# Windows Media Player object c# - playout buffer value

Tags: c#, windows, buffer, windows-media-player

I would like to see the current playout buffer value while streaming a video on a network over a wireless link,

I couldn't find any software that does this so i have decided to write a small app that can show me the current buffer size.

I have put a windows media player object in a form which plays a video from a URL that I specify, Is there any way to display the current buffer size s the video is played out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `bufferingProgress` property with this code:

```
int progressPercent = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.network.bufferingProgress;
```

IWMPNetwork interface
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd563492(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Does this give me a percentage as i keep receiving a value of 100?

Comment: Yes, it's the percentage, check out the documentation, I updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for the link! Do you know of a way to get the actual size of the buffer being used?